# How to convert "language" to "numeric" in "R"?

Tags: r

Good day. I'm trying to check whether or not the function has a minimum at point.

For that I use derivatives and Hessian matrices.

The problem is that derivatives are stored in type "language", while I need them in "numeric".

For example, I use

```
der_x1 <- D(expression(3 + 2 * x_1 + 3 * x_2 + 2 * (x_1)^2 + 2 * x_1 * x_2 + 6 * (x_2)^2), "x_1")
der_x1x1 <- D(der_x1, "x_1")
```

And get `der_x1x1 = 2 * 2`.

`typeof(der_x1x1)` returns "`language`".

But to find the determinant of the Hessian matrix I need R to simplify `2 * 2` to `4` and convert it to number.

If I try `as.numeric(der_x1x1)`, I get `Error: 'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: Wrap it in `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```
 eval(der_x1x1)
 x_1 <- 1
 x_2 <- 1
 eval(der_x1)
```

Comment: Thank you immensely, Siyu Sun, it does exactly what I need.